# jquery add row in table with .after()

Tags: javascript, html

```
var stop_index = 1;

$('.add_stop').click(function(){
        tr = '#stop' + stop_index
        $(tr).after('<tr id="stop'+ stop_index + '"><td>'+ stop_index +'</td></tr>');
        stop_index ++;
});
```

This is code (add a row in a table).

But, It doesn't works.

If I write code like this, it works.

`$('#stop1').after('<tr id="stop'+ stop_index + '"><td>'+ stop_index +'</td></tr>');`

What is the problem?

Comment: Is your `stop_index` variable edited somewhere else?

Comment: can you share code at jsfillde

Comment: Your code will result in multiple items with the same id (stopx), which is not allowed in html.

Comment: You need to do `stop_index++` before you call `.after()`, so the new row gets a different index.

Comment: are you appending row after a last row always?

Comment: is that worked for you ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code you would already need a `<tr id="stop1">` element for this to work, and then the next one is also added with id `stop1`. Perhaps you should be incrementing the value earlier

```js
var stop_index = 1;

$('.add_stop').click(function(){
        tr = '#stop' + stop_index
        stop_index ++;
        $(tr).after('<tr id="stop'+ stop_index + '"><td>'+ stop_index +'</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="stop1"><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
<button class="add_stop">
Add
</button>
```

Having incrementing id's is a bit of an anti-pattern though, you should consider if you need them at all. Its much simpler to just add to the end of the existing list if you're just trying to add rows

```js
var index = 1;
$('.add_stop').click(function(){      
    $('table').append('<tr><td>'+ ++index +'</td></tr>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
<button class="add_stop">
Add
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're incrementing `stop_index` after you create the new row, not before it. So when you add the first new row, it will have `id=stop1`, not `id=stop2`. The next time you try to add a new row, you'll try to add it after `#stop2`, but that row doesn't exist, so nothing happens.

Just move the line

```
stop_index++;
```

up one line.

```
$('.add_stop').click(function(){
    tr = '#stop' + stop_index
    stop_index ++;
    $(tr).after('<tr id="stop'+ stop_index + '"><td>'+ stop_index +'</td></tr>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
$('.add_stop').click(function(){
   tr = '#stop' + stop_index;
   //to generate uniq id you need to plus it bore adding new tr
   let newTrIDIndex = stop_index + 1;
   $(tr).after('<tr id="stop'+ newTrIDIndex + '"><td>'+ newTrIDIndex +'</td></tr>');
    stop_index = newTrIDIndex ;
});
```

if you dont do plus then you are creating tr with old index , and that means you end of with two tr with same id. so to avoid it created index value before creating tr.

Answer (score -1):

you would use

```
$("#" + id + ).closest( "tr" ).after( ... );
```

or you could also use

```
$( ... ).insertAfter( $("#" + id ).closest( "tr" ) );
```

which is essentially equivalent.

See http://api.jquery.com/after/ for full details.